# Tools for conversion of a machine-readable list of misspellings autocorrection to an Emacs abbrev table

Tags: abbrev

There is already a sample autocorrection abbrev_defs file on Emacs wiki:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/autocorrection_abbrev_defs

There are other more comprehensive common misspellings autocorrection in other places for example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings/For_machines
and https://gist.github.com/drashna/46c64ea29a382f754b2cf957ebd8e924#file-autocorrect_dict_larger-txt-L292

The format of these machine ready autocorractions is typically of the following format:

```
abandonned ->abandoned
aberation -> aberration
abilityes->  abilities
abilties->abilities
```

There could be some blank spaces between `->` and the previous word and the next word.

Assume we have a file whose lines are like above lines. Is there any tool to convert this file a ready-to-use abbrev_defs file like below?

```
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table '(
    ("abandonned" "abandoned" nil 0)
    ("aberation" "aberration" nil 0)
    ("abilityes" "abilities" nil 0)
    ("abilties" "abilities" nil 0)
))
```

Comment: That's a super simple regexp replacement, surely?

Answer (score 0):

If your  `input.txt` is like this

```
abandonned ->abandoned
aberation -> aberration
abilityes->  abilities
abilties->abilities
```

and you want to convert it to `output.el` that contains this

```lisp
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table
  '(("abandonned" "abandoned" nil 0)
    ("aberation" "aberration" nil 0)
    ("abilityes" "abilities" nil 0)
    ("abilties" "abilities" nil 0)))
```

then copy the snippet below to your `*scratch*` buffer, do `ESC->`, and do `C-x C-e`

```lisp
(require 'rx)
(require 'f)
(require 's)

(-> `(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table
       ',(->> (-> "input.txt"
          (f-read-text 'utf-8)
          s-lines)
          (-filter #'org-string-nw-p)
          (--map (split-string it "->" nil (rx (one-or-more whitespace))))
          (--map (-concat it (list nil 0)))))
    pp-to-string
    (f-write-text 'utf-8 "output.el"))
```

For the above snippet to work you need to install `dash`, `s` and `f` libraries from `MELPA`.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-off conversion, the simplest method is to use `query-replace-regexp` (bound to `C-M-%`, i.e. `C-M-S-5`).

Select the whole file as the region, and do `C-M-%`, use `\(\w+\) *-> *\(\w+\)` as the regexp to match and     `("\1" "\2" nil 0))` as the replacement, press `<SP>` (i.e. just a space character) to see it in action once, press `!` to do all the rest of them if you are satisfied.

Then add the beginning and ending lines by hand.

**Longer Explanation**: `\w+` matches a sequence of one or more "word" characters, `\(\w+\)` does the same thing but remembers what it matched, so it can be used in the replacement string by using the constructs `\1`, `\2`, etc. (for the first pair of escaped parens, second pair, etc.),  `*` matches 0 or more spaces, `->` is a literal match to those characters.

So we match (and remember) the first word, then an arbitrary number of spaces, then `->`, then an arbitrary number of spaces, then the second word (and remember it). In the replacement string    `("\1" "\2" nil 0)`, the `\1` is replaced by the fist remembered string and `\2` is replaced by the second remembered string.

Refer to the sections on regexps in the chapters on `Searching` in the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search.html) and the [Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-and-Matching.html) manual for these details on regexps (and much more). Or use `C-h i g(emacs)RET m search` and `C-h i g(elisp)RET m searching` to read the chapters in emacs itself (IMO, a much superior way to search the Emacs documentation).